# JavaScript local storage, function getTitle

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a problem with local storage. I want to write JS function "getTitle", which verifies the existence of variable "title". 
If variable exist, then function returns the value of title. 
If variable does not exist, then "local storage" creates with the default value (define yourself) and from this function returns the value

This is what I have so far

```
function getTitle() {
    if (window.localStorage.title) {
          title_tmp = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem('title'));
          print = window.localStorage.getItem('data');
          $("#print").html(print);
    } else {
        window.localStorage.setItem('title', title_tmp);
    }
 }
```

Comment: And what is exactly not working with that?

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment...

Comment: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: It is homework assignment, and I don't know how to start. This is what i have.
    function getTitle(){
 if (window.localStorage.title) {

            title_tmp = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem('title'));
            print = window.localStorage.getItem('data');

            $("#print").html(print);
        }else {
            window.localStorage.setItem('title', title_tmp);
        }
}

Comment: Have you tried calling that function and seeing what happens?